# How to get from Gatwick airport to Paddington?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, london, lgw

What's the most straightforward way to get from Gatwick airport to Paddington station in London using public transport?

I'm mostly interested in travel time & general smoothness of the trip (e.g. buying just one ticket for the whole trip would be nice). Price is a secondary concern.

Comment: On a slight tangent, most long-distance trains out of Paddington call at Reading, which is connected to Gatwick by [a direct train service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Downs_Line) - that said, services on this line are infrequent, and the trains that run it are built for neither comfort *nor* speed. The scenery is pleasantly rural considering how close you are to London, mind.

Comment: how much luggage will you have? Navigating a central london tube with lots of luggage is a fools errand. Gawd knows how many times ive seen people do it at rush hour.WHY?. Get the 1st part for certain, the Gatwick express but get in big black cab for the second part, no stress. Are you catching at a train from Paddington (why else would you go there?) If you are then where as the advice would be different as you could catch airport buses/trains further west.

Comment: I didn't find it too difficult at all to navigate the tube with a backpack and a carry-on size suitcase. Both company office and hotel being located next to Paddington station is one reason to go there. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be taking the [**Gatwick Express**](http://www.gatwickexpress.com/) to Victoria Station (the journey is about 30 mins). The Gatwick Station is directly connected to the South Terminal. From the North Terminal it's a bit further and you need to take the automated shuttle train. 
Trains leave every 15 minutes.

From Victoria Station you have no less than three options:

- take the underground/tube/metro/whatever-you-call-it **Circle Line**
  (High Street Kensington direction) and get out at Paddington stop.
  It's gonna take about 20 minutes.
- Accordingly to Gagravarr's comment you could also go from **Victoria Line** to Oxford Circus, then a cross-platform change to the **Bakerloo Line** up to
  Paddington.
- If the metro is closed, take the bus 436 to Paddington.

For all those options, make sure you use the exit at the front of the train, not the exit on the upper floor through the elevators or escalators.

You could also take a taxi, if the price isn't a concern for you.

There are other possibilities I left out because they won't be faster or more straightforward than this.

Note: be aware of the fact that, [from time to time, especially during weekends/holidays, Gatwick Express has to make alterations to train services, usually for planned Improvement works.](http://www.gatwickexpress.com/en/your-journey/timetable/improvement-works/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can buy one ticket from the airport that's valid for the tube trip too?

Comment: Price is not a concern right now (my employer pays), but if there's a *good* public transport option available, 
I prefer that for other reasons. :)

Comment: @Jonik gotcha :-) Anyway, there isn't a single ticket valid for both the train and the metro but you can purchase the metro ticket at the Gatwick Station: http://www.gatwickexpress.com/en/london/london-underground/

Comment: Much quicker for the tube would be Victoria Line to Oxford Circus, then a cross-platform change to the Bakerloo Line up to Paddington. The circle line all that way round is ssllllooowwww....

Comment: @Gagravarr not sure about that but I'm gonna integrated your suggestion in the answer, thank you!

Comment: @Gagravarr You're right that it's quicker but for someone not familiar with London the circle line option is foolproof. Also changing at Oxford Circus isn't much fun especially with luggage.

Comment: The cross platform change is just fine with luggage - off one train, wheel your bags 50m, board next one. Any other change there is a bit of a nightmare, but northbound-northbound or southbound-southbound between victoria and bakerloo lines are really easy changes

Comment: Sorry for delay. One correction: it **is** possible to buy one ticket for both the train & tube, according to personnel at Gatwick airport train station. (At that point I'd already purchased train-only ticket from a vending machine, so I didn't try it myself.) Other than that, accepted.

Answer (score 15):

I realise that this an older question, but I've done this journey many times, and the easiest way in my opinion is to take the [**Thameslink**](http://www.thameslinkrailway.com/) service, as stated in the other answers, but to remain on until **Farringdon**. Farringdon is a much easier change when you have luggage as the railway lines run in parallel with the underground. It also has a shorter journey to Paddington (about 14 minutes on either Circle Line or Hammersmith & City Line).

You can purchase a combined rail and tube ticket at Gatwick, but trying to find it in the automated ticket machine can be tricky, so I would suggest going to the manned ticket office, ask for a ticket to London including a single tube journey to Paddington, travelling with Thameslink (was FCC/First Capital Connect until late 2014).  The ticket will read something like Gatwick Airport to London U1  (U1 being the underground zone that Paddington is in).  The train you want will probably have a have a destination of Bedford, or Luton. But the signboards at Gatwick will tell you the destination, calling points, and operating company.

Comment: Farringdon is also a better stop, as Thameslink services will not stop at London Bridge from 2015, and will be diverted via Elephant and Castle. Blackfriars, Farringdon and St Pancras will still be served by them though.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the cheapest route would be to get a [Thamelink train](http://www.thameslinkrailway.com/) to London Bridge (not Gatwick Express, this is an unnecessary expense in my opinion) this takes 28 mins. Then get the Westbound Jubilee Line (Grey Line) to Baker Street. Cross the platform to the Bakerloo line (quick interchange) Northbound 3 stops to Paddington.

Comment: If you add a link to the ticket page of the the train it would be a great answer.

Comment: Sure Vince, no problem - http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/

Comment: I would like to go to PAddington from Gatwick on Monday. Due to the cancellation of Gatwick Express i am looking for other choices. But the First Capital as you mention does not take only 28 minutes but 1h30h on average accordnig to the site

Comment: Also why http://www.southernrailway.com/ links to gatwick express?

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this question (and many others) will change in late 2018 or early 2019 when the [Elizabeth Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Line) opens.

For future reference, board a **Thameslink** train at Gatwick (the likely destinations for this service are Bedford, Luton, Peterborough, Cambridge or King's Lynn) and change at **Farringdon** for an **Elizabeth Line** train to Paddington.

Because this journey will be entirely on National Rail, you can get a through ticket without needing Underground - a normal ticket to "London Terminals" should be valid on the entire route.

Note that if you are travelling to Paddington for Heathrow, then the Elizabeth Line service from Farringdon will include direct trains to Heathrow Airport (the main station at Terminals 1-3; you may need to change there for a shuttle train to T4 or T5).

Hopefully it will be a bit less than the £66.50 that Gatwick Express + Heathrow Express currently costs!

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to put this answer in now, as it may confuse people in the next 4-5 years, and also bits about Heathrow aren't completely confirmed yet

Comment: I was thinking about putting it as a comment to @Martin Jevon's answer above, but couldn't fit it easily in the comment box.

Hopefully, the first sentence will be enough warning!

Comment: I tend to agree with @Gagravarr. Btw, you might want to clarify "£66.50 this journey currently costs", which seems misleading. I mean, I paid **about £20** last year for the Gatwick—Paddington trip (£14.40 to Victoria, plus tube).

Comment: I'd be wary of making any kind of statement about Crossrail fares and ticketing until such time as a normal member of the public actually travels for the first time...

Comment: Additionally, it's not called Crossrail any more - they've just decided it'll be called the Elizabeth Line

Comment: @Gagravarr Good point!

Comment: Given it'll be under the TfL umbrella, I doubt the statement "Because this journey will be entirely on National Rail, you can get a through ticket without needing Underground" will hold.

Comment: @jcaron You may be right, but you can get no-dagger tickets for TfL Rail (future Crossrail)

Answer (score -3):

You can take Gatwick Express train service, It runs non-stop every 15 minutes with a journey time of 30 minutes.

Comment: Except it doesn't go to Paddington, does it? It goes to Chapham Junction and/or London Victoria, or London Bridge?

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers, and is misleading as Mark pointed out.